# Overcompensation Value-Financial Mathematics

Tags: probability, martingales, finance

**EXERCISE**

> We consider a free from arbitrage financial market $(Ω,F,P,S_0,S_1)$ with $α<S_0^{1}\cdot(1+r)<β$,where $$0<α:=min_{ω \in Ω} S_1^{1}(ω), β:=max_{ω \in Ω}S_1^{1}, α<β$$
>
> Let C be a financial derivative of the form $C:=h(S_1^{1})$ where $h\geq0$ is a convex function.Show that the overcompensation value $\overline π(C)$ of derivative $C$ is given by the formula
>
> $$\overline π(C)=\dfrac{h(β)}{1+r}\cdot \dfrac{(1+r)S_0^{1}-α}{β-α}+\dfrac{α}{1+r}\cdot \dfrac{β-(1+r)S_0^{1}}{β-α}$$

**QUESTIONS**

We have that :
$$α<S_0^{1}\cdot(1+r)<β$$ and $$0<min_{ω \in Ω} S_1^{1}(ω)<S_0^{1}\cdot(1+r)<max_{ω \in Ω} S_1^{1}(ω)$$

We have also that $$α<β\Longrightarrow min_{ω \in Ω} S_1^{1}(ω)<max_{ω \in Ω} S_1^{1}(ω)$$

We have a financial market with no-arbitrage so we have the form:
$$π(C)=E_Q\bigg[\dfrac{c}{1+r}\bigg]<\infty$$ for $Q\subset P$

So,I am new in financial Mathematics and i don't have the experience to understand how to proceed with this data!Can anyone help me with this?How can i use the fact that function $h \geq 0$ is a convex function.Did i miss any data from what the exercise gives me?How can i start so to estimate $\overline π(C)$

**I would really appreciate any hints/thorough solution because I don't have any experience in this type of exercise.**

Thanks, in advance!

Comment: Another question that dresses up an obvious idea using "fancy maths". Not your fault, MKM - a lot of math finance fits into that category.

Comment: Cross-posted in https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/42648/.

Comment: @RichardMartin The problem is that our professor doesn't show us any example of these types of problems in class!So,i have many questions.But thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$h\le L$ where $L$ is the linear function joining $(\alpha,h(\alpha))$ to $(\beta,h(\beta))$. Then calculate the discounted expected payoff of $L$.